# C# - Habilitar o deshabilitar botón desde otro formulario

Tags: c#

Tengo un botón llamado siguiente en el formulario **`registrar_alumno`** que por defecto está des habilitado.

Al momento de habilitarlo desde el **form 2** me arroja el siguiente error:

> **Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.**

**Mi código:**

```
registrar_alumno ab = Owner as registrar_alumno;
ab.siguiente.Enabled = true;
```

Este código lo utilizo para llamar al formulario **registrar_alumnos** desde el **form2** y activar el botón.

Comment: te habilita el boton y te da el error? o te da el error y no te lo habilita, ya que si es esta ultima posiblemente y como dice el error lo estas referenciando mal

Answer (score 0):

Si usas el `Owner` quiere decir que cuando muestras el `form2` en el `Show()` debes pasar la instancia del form desde donde lo inicias (en tu caso el `registrar_alumno`)

Desde el `registrar_alumno`, algo como ser:

```
public void button1_Click(...){

   Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
   frm2.Show(this);

}
```

ese `this` que uso en el `Show()` asigna el `owner`

De esta forma cuando uses

```
registrar_alumno ab = this.Owner as registrar_alumno;
```

deberias poder convertir correctamente